# Restoring in-app purchases bug: restores even if not purchased

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

One (honest) user has just informed me that it's possible to "buy" the in-app purchase of my app by simply pressing the RESTORE button even if the in-app purchase has not been purchased.
This is the code I'm using (that I thought it was sufficient ... but I was wrong):

```
 - (IBAction) restore {

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
    }


- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *) transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

        switch(transaction.transactionState){

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing ...");

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");

                [self activatePurchase];

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];


                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");

                if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {

                    //the user cancelled the payment ;(
                }

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred:

                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Deferred");

                break;
        }
    }
}




- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    [self activatePurchase];

}
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Using `if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
  SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}` worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payment observer method `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is called when the payment queue is finished restoring transactions, regardless of whether any transactions were actually restored. You will get one call to `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` every time you call `restoreCompletedTransactions` even if there were 0 calls to `updatedTransactions`.

As a result, you are calling `activatePurchase` even if there was no purchase.

The correct place to activate the purchase is in the `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` case in `updateTransactions`; just as you do for the `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` case.

Comment: I've moved `activatePurchase` to `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` but it seems `paymentQueue:queue updatedTransactions: transactions` is never called even if `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` is present in `- (IBAction) restore`.

Comment: Do you have a purchase to restore for that test user?

Comment: My fault ... I was using the wrong account! Can I ask you if there is any way I can detect that there is nothing to restore (to give some feedback to the user)?

Comment: Sure, you can set a Boolean in the `SKPaymentStateRestored` case. If you get to `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` And the Boolean is false you know that nothing was restored.